# DataGridView skipping lines VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm displaying data from a .txt file into a datagridview which works fine but once I press the button to display another line of data the datagridview row cell is skipping 7 lines. I don't know if this problem can be resolved in the datagridview properties or in the code itself. I have tried each way but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution

```
 Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim rowvalue As String
    Dim cellvalue(0) As String

    Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = NewIO.StreamReader("button1.txt")
    'Reading CSV file content 
    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
        rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
        cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c) 'Separating
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellvalue)
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Dim cellvalue(0) As String` creates an array of strings that is only one element in length, however when you assign it a value you are trying to set it to an array of an unknown length. You should also be utilizing a `using` statement with the streamreader object.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I thought letting cell value=row.value was assigning it to a value. What way do you think I should do this?

Comment: You need to provide more information before anyone can realistically help you. Please provide a sample content of the `button1.txt` file, let us know how the datagridview was setup column names or databinding, etc. Please take a look at [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)